# Choosing Python 3 libraries for GIS analysis?

Tags: python, shapefile, geojson, software-recommendations

I am trying to do some spatial data analysis in Python 3 now, and I was wondering what the best libraries are for GIS in Python 3. The Fiona library was developed with Python 3.3 but the Python 3+ version of Shapely is still in development. Other libraries have been ported over to Python 3 but I am not sure if they have been thoroughly tested and validated compared to their Python 2 counterparts.

The basic functionalities that I need are as follows.

- Mapping Shapefiles or GeoJSON
- Associating polygons with points and lines
- Mapping vector data as well as raster data

Can you provide some suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [osgeo.ogr and osgeo.gdal](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/1.10.0) -> the base, doing everything you want
- [Fiona](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fiona/1.0.2) -> Mapping Shapefiles or GeoJSON
- [Pyshp (shapefile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshp/1.2.0)) -> Mapping Shapefiles or GeoJSON (pure Python)

[image]

If you look at the [Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi), it  is indicated:

Fiona -> yes
[image]

Shapely -> no
[image]